# Akavache can not open database file

Tags: android, sqlite, mono, xamarin

I have two projects - a PCL (profile 7) and an Android application (targeting API ... but as an aside I want it to target 10).

The PCL has installed akavache from Nuget. The Android app has installed akavache.sqlite3. For the latter I also had to reference Rx-PlatformServices so that the projects would build.

The Android app references the PCL.

There is a button on the default Android activity wired up as follows:

```cs
button.Click += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var d = new DataService();
    await d.SaveData();
    var ss = await d.LoadData();
    button.Text = ss;
};
```

The PCL has the following code.

```cs
public class DataService
{
    private IBlobCache blobStore;

    public DataService()
    {
        BlobCache.ApplicationName = "DamienApp";
        this.blobStore = BlobCache.UserAccount;
    }
    public async Task SaveData()
    {
        var data = new Person {Name = "Sienna", Age = 3};
        await this.blobStore
                    .InsertObject<string>("mykey", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
    }

    public async Task<string> LoadData()
    {
        var data = await this.blobStore.GetObjectAsync<string>("mykey");
        return data;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

On pressing the button I'm given the following error.

> [mono] Unhandled Exception: [mono] SQLite.SQLiteException: Could not
>   open database file: BlobCache/userblobs.db (CannotOpen) [mono]   at
>   SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (System.String databasePath,
>   SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x0006d] in
>   /Users/paul/github/Akavache/Akavache.Sqlite3/SQLite.cs:125  [mono]
>   at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionWithoutLock..ctor
>   (SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString connectionString, SQLiteOpenFlags
>   flags) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/paul/github/Akavache/Akavache.Sqlite3/SQLiteAsync.cs:344 
>   [mono]   at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool+Entry..ctor
>   (SQLite.SQLiteConnectionString connectionString, SQLiteOpenFlags
>   flags) [0x0000d] in
>   /Users/paul/github/Akavache/Akavache.Sqlite3/SQLiteAsync.cs:330 
>   [mono]   at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool+c__AnonStorey14.<>m__25
>   (Int32 _) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/paul/github/Akavache/Akavache.Sqlite3/SQLiteAsync.cs:309 
>   [mono]   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator10`2[System.Int32,SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool+Entry].MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0  [mono]   at System.C

I'm wondering if it's some kind of security issue. This is all running my phone (Galaxy note 2) to which I have root access.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a million years from when you asked it, but you probably didn't set the Application Name:

```
BlobCache.ApplicationName = "MyAppName";
```

Comment: Hah! Thanks Paul. Look - it's a while back and I ended up just rolling my own. From memory though, I 'remember knowing' that ApplicationName needed to be set so my gut feel is it was something else. You might be right though.